# Airflow network access through raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, airflow, portforwarding

I have been struggling a bit to get access to airflow from outsite my network.
I have airflow running on a raspberry pi 4, and all seems to be working just fine, I can access it via http://localhost:8080.

I have also set forwarding rules in my home router pointing to the raspberry pi:
[image: Port forwarding specifications]

The port forwarding is working since I can see it open using an external tool, and I have also set up a SSH port forwarding to access my raspberry pi from outside my local network.
So accessing http://my-public-ip:123 should be taking me to my aiflow web ui, but instead I just got "This site can't be reached".

Can anybody spot what I have done wrong or if I skipped any step of the process?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running Airflow with Docker or you have it installed? If using Docker, setting the webserver's service port to `127.0.0.1:8080:8080` it's the first step.
Secondly, you might need to look into the [config webserver options](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#webserver). You will need to set the `AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__BASE_URL: 'http[s]://your_address/airflow'` environment variable and install a reverse proxy (I suggest you **nginx**); you can find more details [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/run-behind-proxy.html). After you've done this, don't forget to also set the environment variable `AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__ENABLE_PROXY_FIX: 'true`